# My lambda handler function inside of bar.js is not hit when I load www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar. Why?

Tags: lambda, netlify

I am using Netlify. I have created a lambda handler function inside of bar.js

See the code below to see the function I am trying to run. It runs if I go to www.mywebsite.com/bar, but it doesn't run when I go to www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar.

In this case, "foo" will be variable. It may be mywebsite.com/something/bar. I can't predict what the first path part will be, but I need to use it to place it in the endpoint url's query for "product" (also shown below).

How can I add a handler to an unknown path? I know "bar" will always be "bar", but I can't predict the preceding portion.

```
var getURL = (product) => `www.randomdatabase.com/?product=${product}`;

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log('handler in bar.js ran');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work using proxy rewrites on Netlify. The issue is going to be managing the static assets if you want to run a site at the same time from the root path of the domain.

There's some base knowledge needed of how the CDN for Netilify works with their function paths that might help.

- All functions on Netlify for your site are at the `/.netlify/functions/<function name>` endpoint
- There is not a way to proxy rewrite a path with wildcards like `/*/bar` to determine a path to `bar.js` function as an example. You would have to have the endpoint for the function start with some known path.

You could go from the root path starting with the product, but that is going to create it's own issues when/if you want to have static assets on the root path like `/index.html`, but it can be done by listing all static assets in the redirects configuration (not scale-able).

Here are both examples of what you would need to do to accomplish dynamic parts in the path.

### Option 1: from root of domain `/<product-id>`

`_redirects` in root of site

```
/ /index.html 200
/* /.netlify/functions/product/:splat 200
```

add a function `product.js` to the functions folder

```js
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  // path will come in as `/<some-product-id>/<rest>
  const pathArr = event.path.split("/");
  const productId = pathArr[1];
  console.log(`Product id is ${productId}`);

  const body = productId
    ? `<h1>Product id = ${productId}</h1>`
    : "Missing product!";
  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `${body}`
  });
};
```

### Option 2: from `/product` of domain `/product/<product-id>`

`_redirects` in root of site

```
/product/* /.netlify/functions/product/:splat 200
```

add a function `product.js` to the functions folder

```js
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  // path will come in as `/product/<some-product-id>/<rest>
  const pathArr = event.path.split("/");
  const productId = pathArr[2];
  console.log(`Product id is ${productId}`);

  const body = productId
    ? `<h1>Product id = ${productId}</h1>`
    : "Missing product!";
  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `${body}`
  });
};
```

Note: [Here is a GitHub repository](https://github.com/talves/netlify-lambda-product-proxy) with the master branch as [Option 2](https://github.com/talves/netlify-lambda-product-proxy/tree/master) and from-root branch as [Option 1](https://github.com/talves/netlify-lambda-product-proxy/tree/from-root).